# complete missing rows in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to complete the data frame so that all variables within `Group` is represented for all `Type` by adding `0` if they are missing in original input data. Please see example out.

In:

```
> data.frame(Group=c("Chemo","ADT","Immune","Chemo","ADT"), Type=c("CRC","CRC","CRC","Lung","Lung"), value=c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.1))
   Group Type value
1  Chemo  CRC   0.5
2    ADT  CRC   0.4
3 Immune  CRC   0.1
4  Chemo Lung   0.3
5    ADT Lung   0.1
```

Out:

```
> data.frame(Group=c("Chemo","ADT","Immune","Chemo","ADT","Immune"), Type=c("CRC","CRC","CRC","Lung","Lung","Lung"), value=c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.1,0))
   Group Type value
1  Chemo  CRC   0.5
2    ADT  CRC   0.4
3 Immune  CRC   0.1
4  Chemo Lung   0.3
5    ADT Lung   0.1
6 Immune Lung   0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Group = c("Chemo", "ADT", "Immune", "Chemo", "ADT"),
  Type = c("CRC", "CRC", "CRC", "Lung", "Lung"),
  value = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1)
)

theGrid <- expand.grid(Group = unique(df$Group), Type = unique(df$Type))

combined <- merge(df, theGrid, all.y = TRUE)
combined$value <- ifelse(is.na(combined$value), 0, combined$value)
#  sort by type and then group
combined[order(combined$Type, combined$Group), ]
```

...and the output:

```r
> #  sort by type and then group
> combined[order(combined$Type, combined$Group), ]
   Group Type value
1    ADT  CRC   0.4
3  Chemo  CRC   0.5
5 Immune  CRC   0.1
2    ADT Lung   0.1
4  Chemo Lung   0.3
6 Immune Lung   0.0
```

### Alternatives to ifelse()

A commenter asked why I used `ifelse()` in the solution rather than an assignment operator with a row-based condition combined with the `[` form of the extract operator, asserting that these options would be much faster than `ifelse()`.

This is easily verified with `microbenchmark()`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

tm <- microbenchmark(
     combined$value <- ifelse(is.na(combined$value),0,combined$value),
     combined$value[is.na(combined$value)] <- 0,
     transform(combined, replace(value, is.na(value), 0)),
               times=1000
)
ggplot2::autoplot(tm)
```

...and the results:

[image]

A quick `summary()` tells us that `transform()` and the combination of the assignment operator and `[` form of the extract operator are about about 45% faster than `ifelse()`, and the difference in average performance is less than 9 microseconds per call.

```
> summary(tm)
                                                                expr    min      lq
1 combined$value <- ifelse(is.na(combined$value), 0, combined$value) 13.794 14.9325
2                         combined$value[is.na(combined$value)] <- 0  7.654  8.6085
3               transform(combined, replace(value, is.na(value), 0))  6.777  7.9185
       mean  median      uq    max neval cld
1 16.042322 15.5045 16.3100 48.070  1000   c
2  9.374198  8.9445  9.3845 60.349  1000  b 
3  8.704229  8.4660  8.9205 38.122  1000 a
```

### Expanding the Data Size

A commenter asserted that the above benchmarks weren't meaningful due to the size of the data frame used in the benchmark. When we increase the size of the data frame to 1,000,000 rows and rerun the test, some interesting patterns emerge.

For this run of the test we also include the tidyverse version of the answer that was posted by another person.

First, we'll expand the data per the comments.

```
set.seed(108970777) # for reproducibility
combined2 <- combined[sample.int(nrow(combined), 1e6, replace=TRUE), ]
```

Next, we'll run the benchmark.

```
tm <- microbenchmark(
     combined2$value <- ifelse(is.na(combined2$value),0,combined$value),
     combined2$value[is.na(combined2$value)] <- 0,
     transform(combined2, replace(value, is.na(value), 0)),
     combined2 %>% 
          complete(Group, Type, fill = list(value = 0)),
     times=100
)
```

Finally, we'll print a violin plot and descriptive statistics.

```
ggplot2::autoplot(tm)
theSummary <- summary(tm)
theSummary$range <- theSummary$max - theSummary$min
theSummary
```

[image]

[image]

First, the range of test results across the approaches is surprisingly consistent. The approach with the largest range is the tidyverse approach at 170 milliseconds, whereas the one with the minimum range is assignment / extract operator combination at just under 129 milliseconds.

However, when we review the percentile statistics, we see that `transform()` is the clear winner for consistent performance, as its 75%ile score is 2.67 milliseconds, whereas the next closest approach clocks in at 26.05 milliseconds.

Additional, more detailed analysis of the behavior of the functions is needed to understand the sources of variability in the performance of each function.

### Performance vs. Convenience

The comment thread to my answer began with a comparison of the performance of a Base R solution and a tidyverse solution.  Even on a data frame of 1,000,000 rows, the tidyverse solution runs at a 75%ile of 151 milliseconds,  or less than two tenths of a second.

For the average R user, the difference between the 2.67 millisecond 75%ile performance of the `transform()` approach and the slowest 75%ile of all the approaches is negligible, especially if `complete()` is executed only once in a tidyverse pipeline.

That said, with a large data frame containing large number of columns that require recoding of missing values, "your mileage may vary."  Another consideration is CPU and RAM speed. These tests were run on a machine with an AMD Ryzen 9 5950X CPU running at 4.9 GHz using 3600 MHz RAM. Slower machines are likely to return results that show higher variability between the fastest and slowest approaches. Finally, tests may be impacted by other processes that are active on the computer while the tests are running.

Comment: I checked with microbenchmark that this base solution is six times faster (for example dataset) than tidyr::complete solution.  BTW. the result rownames should be reset:)

Comment: Why the `ifelse`? `combined$value[is.na(combined$value)] <- 0` or `transform(combined, replace(value, is.na(value), 0))` should be much faster.

Comment: @jay.sf - thanks for the feedback. See the updated answer for my response to your feedback.

Comment: Nice you're doing benchmarks! However, generally we use a much larger data frame for benchmarks, `df_bm <- df[sample.int(nrow(df), 1e5, replace=TRUE), ]` to make the benchmark meaningful.

Comment: PS: Using `times=3` in `microbenchmark` should suffice to get a first glance then.

Comment: @jay.sf - thanks. I updated my answer to include tests on a larger data set.  Setting `times=` to a larger value makes the violin plots more meaningful. Also, love the use of the 'royal we' in the comments.

Comment: Good job! Upvoted.

Comment: @jay.sf - thanks for challenging me to improve my answer. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with [`tidyr::complete()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html).

First you specify the columns you want to expand to all possible combinations and then you can specify values to fill in the other columns if missing. Default is `NA` so you need to supply the value of `0`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(Group=c("Chemo","ADT","Immune","Chemo","ADT"), Type=c("CRC","CRC","CRC","Lung","Lung"), value=c(0.5,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.1))

d %>% 
  complete(Group, Type, fill = list(value = 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Group  Type  value
#>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 ADT    CRC     0.4
#> 2 ADT    Lung    0.1
#> 3 Chemo  CRC     0.5
#> 4 Chemo  Lung    0.3
#> 5 Immune CRC     0.1
#> 6 Immune Lung    0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>